# Error: two or more data types in declaration of function?

Tags: c++, if-statement, types, declaration

My plan was to make a simple addition calculator, and move on from there.
Remember, this is my first day coding.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int a;
int b;
int sum;
string ans;

class CalcClass{
public:
    int add (int a, int b) {
        cout << "Pick the numbers you want to add" << endl;
        cin >> a >> b;
        sum = a + b;
        return sum;
    }
};
```

Added `string ans;` (at the top). Now I'm getting an `"error: no matching function for call to 'CalcClass::add()'"`

Why would it be saying this if I already created `calcObject` and used `calcObject.add();` to call the function?

```
void pickFunction(){
    cout << "What Function do you want to do? \n Add, Subtract, multiply, or divide? ";
    cin >> ans;

    if (ans == "add"){
        CalcClass calcObject;
        calcObject.add();
    }


int main(){
    pickFunction();

    cout << "Your answer is : " << sum << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I put the `pickFunction()` in main. Also the Class is defined before the function. The only problem I have no is the {, } brackets in the main. What looks wrong with them?

Comment: Oh no, no, you're not supposed to put the function _itself_ inside of main, just put a function **call** in main (above your print statement).

Comment: I will illustrate in my answer below...

Comment: You're calling the `add()` function with no arguments, but you defined it so it requires two parameters. But since the function doesn't use the initial values of its parameters you should either (a) define it with no parameters, and make `a` and `b` local variables, or (b) define it with two parameters, have it *use* those parameters rather than reading them, and modify the code that calls it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ans` needs a type (probably `string`), `add` needs quotes (`"add"`), `CalcClass.calcObject;` needs to be `CalcClass calcObject;`.

'dot' syntax (`x.y`) is used for accessing data or functions that are stored inside of an object, not a class (e.g. `calcObject.add();` rather than `CalcClass.add();`).

Also, as Mahesh says, `pickFunction();` needs to be in `main`. This should look as follows:

```
void pickFunction(){
    //code
}
int main() {
    pickFunction();
    //...
}
```

Comment: ok, so I fixed the main to call the function. Now how do I declare 'ans'? Would string ans; work?

Comment: So I used string ans; and it seemed to have helped. Now its saying I'm not calling add (will show in above code).

Comment: Generally you should leave the original code and add new code below to reflect changes. The purpose of SO is also to help others who may look at this post later.

Comment: @Bucky you must pass two parameters to `add(int, int)`. It say's 'no matching function for call' because you did not provide an `add()` function that takes no parameters. You must either provide another `add()` that takes no parameters (not what you want), or you must pass two integers to the `add(int, int)` function you already defined.

Comment: Hmm I see. How would I do this? (Last question ;o). I'm gonna try changing `calcObject.add();` to `calcObject.add(int a, int b);` although not sure if this is the solution

Comment: Experimented and changed it to `calcObject.add(a, b)`. I believe thats right.

Comment: I think I almost got it! 1 minor error remaining. In main I'm getting  **error: a function-definition is not allowed here before '{' token** and also **error: expected '}' at end of input**

Comment: That is indeed the way you should call a function. Good job.

Comment: Huh. I don't see anything that would cause that error. What line is the error on?

Comment: I see it. You're missing a closing brace on your `pickFunction()` definition. Often times these errors can be more easily caught if you indent your code.

Comment: Fixed it! Built and ran it with NO errors. Man, what a help you have been. I was gonna just give up but you helped me finish my first little program. Thanks a bunch man. I've learned quite a bit from this and I'm sure it will help me later on. Thanks again, Michael!

Comment: no prob bro, any time. just FYI the way we say thank you on Stack Overflow is to up vote. (It's the up arrow to the left of my answer) =P

Comment: Haha I need some more rep for that (15). But don't worry, I'll do that for sure when I hit 15 rep. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
CalcClass.calcObject;
```

is not the way to create an object. `.` operator should be used to access object's members/methods. So, create an object like -

```
CalcClass calcObject;
```

Also forward declaration of a class isn't useful if object instantiation takes place before compiler can see the definition. So, make sure compiler sees `CalcClass` before the pickFunction(). With that said, you have to call the `pickFunction` from main for your program to do anything useful.

Pick a book from [The Definitive C++ Book Guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) and start reading.

Comment: I'll check it out for sure. Seems like a lot of good sources. Thanks :)